# php recursive static function issue

Tags: php

I am new to php. I am trying to use  below recursive static function, but while executing in my code , I am getting error as :

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function seekKey() in myutil.php on line 36 `(here line number 36 means  seekKey($value, $needle); )`

```
static function seekKey($haystack, $needle)
    {
       $valuesArray=null;

      foreach($haystack as $key => $value){
        if($key === $needle){
          $valuesArray[] = $value; 
        }elseif(is_array($value)){
          self::seekKey($value, $needle);
        }
      }

      $valuesArray = array_merge($valuesArray, seekKey($value, $needle));
      return $valuesArray;
    }
```

Please tell me what I have to change in above code?

Comment: Assuming that `seekKey` is a static method in a class, then you need `self::seekKey($value, $needle);` but as `seekKey()` returns a value, you need to do something with that returned value when you call it recursively as well.... perhaps `$valuesArray = array_merge($valuesArray, seekKey($value, $needle));`

Comment: @MarkBaker I just modified my code above as per your suggestion, could you please check now, is above correct? Please correct me if iam wrong. I am sorry iam very new to php

Comment: is `$valuesArray = array_merge($valuesArray, seekKey($value, $needle));` line 36? The `$value` is out of scope here, it is just definded in your `foreach` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `seekKey()` is a static method in a class, then you need `self::seekKey($value, $needle);` but as `seekKey()` returns a value, you need to do something with that returned value when you call it recursively as well.... perhaps `$valuesArray = array_merge($valuesArray, seekKey($value, $needle));`

```
static function seekKey($haystack, $needle)
{
    $valuesArray=[];

    foreach($haystack as $key => $value){
        if($key === $needle){
            $valuesArray[] = $value; 
        }elseif(is_array($value)){
            $valuesArray = array_merge($valuesArray, self::seekKey($value, $needle));
        }
    }

    return $valuesArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark :) All I need is to change first line ie.,  $valuesArray = array(), instead of null